# Numba throws an error. The condition of a filled or empty array is not triggered

Tags: python, numba

If you do not use njit from numba, then the code works, and gives the desired result. But if you run the script through njit, an error appears.
Code without njit from numba.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
# arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
print(arr1)
print(arr2)

def test(arr1, arr2):
    
    arr = np.array(())
    arr = np.append(arr, arr1)
    arr = np.append(arr, arr2)
    arr = arr.reshape(2, len(arr1)).T
    arr = arr[arr[:, 1] > 0]
    
    if arr.size > 0:
        return arr
    
    if arr.size == 0:
        return np.zeros(9)
    

arr = test(arr1, arr2)
print(arr)
```

Code with njit from numba that throws an error.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
# arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
print(arr1)
print(arr2)

@njit
def test(arr1, arr2):
    
    arr = np.array(())
    arr = np.append(arr, arr1)
    arr = np.append(arr, arr2)
    arr = arr.reshape(2, len(arr1)).T
    arr = arr[arr[:, 1] > 0]
    
    if arr.size > 0:
        return arr
    
    if arr.size == 0:
        return np.zeros(9)
    

arr = test(arr1, arr2)
arr
```

The error that the code throws.

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[132], line 26
     22     if arr.size == 0:
     23         return np.zeros(9)
---> 26 arr = test(arr1, arr2)
     27 arr

File c:\Users\krako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File c:\Users\krako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args..error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Can't unify return type from the following types: array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 2d, C), none
Return of: IR name '$110return_value.4', type 'array(float64, 1d, C)', location: 
...
File "..\..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8380\2522033277.py", line 22:

Return of: IR name '$90return_value.1', type 'array(float64, 2d, C)', location: 
File "..\..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8380\2522033277.py", line 20:
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

How do I fix this error?

I tried to run with and without njit.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to have the output be two dimensional.
Try the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
# arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
print(arr1)
print(arr2)

@njit
def test(arr1, arr2):
    arr = np.array(())
    arr = np.append(arr, arr1)
    arr = np.append(arr, arr2)
    arr = arr.reshape(2, len(arr1)).T
    arr = arr[arr[:, 1] > 0]

    if arr.size > 0:
        return arr

    if arr.size == 0:
        return np.zeros((9, 1))

arr = test(arr1, arr2)
print(arr)
```

This will give

```
[1 2 3 4]
[0 0 0 0]
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

or, uncomenting `arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])`

```
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
[[1. 5.]
 [2. 6.]
 [3. 7.]
 [4. 8.]]
```

If you really need the output to be 1 dimensional in the first case (`[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`) then you can flatten the array afterward.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives the following error.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 26
     22     if arr.size == 0:
     23         return np.zeros((9, 1))
---> 26 arr = test(arr1, arr2)
     27 arr

F
   1985 if num_neg_value == 0:
   1986     if origsize != known_size:
-> 1987         raise ValueError("total size of new array must be unchanged")
   1989 elif num_neg_value == 1:
   1990     # Infer negative dimension
   1991     if known_size == 0:

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: it work on my machine... what versions you are using? Maybe you need to update numba (`pip install numba`)? I have Python v3.8.16, numba 0.57.1

Comment: The code doesn't work. Versions 0.57.1 and 3.10.9.

Comment: Huh.  I just I made a fresh conda environment python v3.10.9 (I'm on macOS) with 
numba v0.57.1, and 
numpy v1.24.4, and
the code I gave above runs for me.

Comment: You removed reference from your error message I surmise, but probably it is coming from `arr.reshape()` call. Are you sure you're using exact same values for arr1 and arr2 as you gave in example?  Because if arr1 and arr2 are different sizes from each other then you can't necessarily reshape them like `arr.reshape(2, len(arr1))`.

Comment: For example, if I use different sized arrays like `arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` and `arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 0])` , then I get your same error message that you post above in the comment.  You must use same size arrays.  Is this the problem for you maybe?